# Load a picture after uploading using PHP and Jquery submit? not working

Tags: php, jquery, image, file-upload

I am looking to display an image as soon as the user uploads an image using php and Jquery? I tried the following code. It is not working? Any corrections?

My index1.php file

```
   <script language="javascript"> 
   <?php
   if(isset($_FILES['image']))
   {
   $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
   $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']; 
   }
   $picture= $file_tmp."/".$file_name;
   ?>
   </script>
   <html>
   <head>
   Disp
   </head>
   <body>
   <form name="example" action ="index1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
   Choose an image
   <input type = "file" name="image" />
   <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
   </form>
   <div id="content">
   The uploaded picture must come here
   </div>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/imagedisplay.js"></script> 

   </body>
   </html>
```

my jquery file is imagedisplay.js

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('input[type="file"]').change(function(){
   $(this).parent().submit();       
   $("#content").html('<img src="<?php echo $picture; ?>" >');

   });
   });
Thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the script in the PHP itself - you cant run php code like `<?php echo $picture; ?>` in the JS file, just use:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> /* imagedisplay.js content */ </script>;
```

Comment: I tried it but returns an error at line 9 <?php
if(isset($_FILES['image']))
   {
     $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
     $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
     $picture= $file_tmp.'/'.$file_name;
     echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js">
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $('input[type="file"]').change(function(){
     $(this).parent().submit();
     $("#content").html('<img src="<?php echo $picture; ?>" >');
     });
     });
         </script>'   ;
}
 ?>

Comment: That's because of the quotes in there - you should add to any single quote ( ' ) backslash before it - ( \' ) inside the `echo`

Comment: Thanks a lot.Now there are no errors but im not getting the image in the div section once i upload a file using the upload button...<?php
if(isset($_FILES['image']))
   {
     $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
     $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
     $picture= $file_tmp.'/'.$file_name;
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js">
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $(\'input[type="file"]\').change(function(){
     $(this).parent().submit();
     $("#content").html(\'<img src="a.png" >\');
     });
     });
         </script>'   ;
}
 ?>

Comment: That's another thing, I didn't saw your full code at first - your code referring to a change event but when the field changed you still don't have `$picture` and you can't call PHP from a javascript like you did - you'll need to send the page somewhere (could be the same page) and than after the PHP will run you'll have the final picture

Comment: Thanks a lot. Seems i need to learn in depth before making some real time web pages. Thanks a lot once again for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you don't understand what PHP is. It's a serverside-language, a preprocessor. As soon as the page is loaded and sent away to the user, all the php is GONE, because all the work it does is done serverside. Hence, preprocessor.

What you need to do is make a separate PHP file that takes an image posted from jQuery as a parameter, and returns the metadata for it, and post to that file.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want this inside the change event:

```
$("#content").html('<img src="<?php echo $picture; ?>" >');
```

Because your change event just resubmitted the page. You should do some form of an if statement, where if $picture is set, then show that code:

```
 <?php if ($picture): ?>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $("#content").html('<img src="<?php echo $picture; ?>">'); 
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**EDITED**

Also, copy your tmp file into a folder that your web server (apache) can read:

```
if(isset($_FILES['image'])) {
    $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name']; 
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $newDir =  "/webdir-on-file-system";
    $staticUrl = "http://static.url";
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $newDir . "/" .$file_name);
    $picture = $staticUrl . "/" .$file_name;
}
```

Also, make sure you have proper permissions to copy into $newDir

Comment: I tried this but still not working<?php
if(isset($_FILES['image']))
   {
     $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
     $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
     $picture= $file_tmp.'/'.$file_name;

 
}
if ($picture){
   echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js">
$("#content").html(\'<img src= $picture />\');
</script>';}

 ?>

Comment: You are trying to view an image that is in the temp directory. You need to first copy the file to a directory that your web server can read. I will edit my answer.